# Generating invoice in django with Shiprocket API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to generate invoice of my order in django with shiprocket API. So far I'm getting success Response but the generated URL of PDF is somewhat not understandable.

#Response Im getting

```
"{\"is_invoice_created\":true,
\"invoice_url\":\"https:\/\/s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\/kr-shipmultichannel-mum\/3116291\/invoices\/Retail000058ba9b309-c4bd-4c06-ba15-2cc76b7c5d1f.pdf\",
\"not_created\":[],\"irn_no\":\"\"}"
```

when I try to access above URL get - `Access-Denied`

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>94ARWRYHGSBEZEH1</RequestId>
<HostId>j32LvksmWatylm3TdFGYuJ1qvBwJ39Lj+qIbbQ3CC7AEcrgHnOYGd9fDocMeEwDD4GpzjXQLQhg=</HostId>
</Error>
```

This is the way I want the url to be

```
https://s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/kr-shipmultichannel-mum/3116291/invoices/Retail000058ba9b309-c4bd-4c06-ba15-2cc76b7c5d1f.pdf
```

When I remove the slashed I get in Response I'm able to download the PDF and that's done manually. So how do I get working URL.

#Views.py

```
class GenerateInvoice(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        order_id = request.query_params.get("ids", None)
        print(order_id)
        data = json.dumps({"ids": [order_id]})
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": settings.SHIPROCKET_TOKEN,
        }
        url = "https://apiv2.shiprocket.in/v1/external/orders/print/invoice"

        response = requests.post(url=url, data=data, headers=headers)

        return Response(response)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the result is response object. Try adding these:

```
response = json.loads(response.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: read() is not working. It shows response object has no attribute read

Comment: response.json() works